# Tarpit-Endlessh: Monitors port 2222 instead of port 22

Tags: server, ssh

I installed on Ubuntu 22.04 tarpit-endlessh (apt install endlessh) and made the following settings in /etc/endlessh/config:

```
port 22
Delay 10000
MaxLineLength 32
MaxClients 4096
LogLevel 0
BindFamily 0
```

```
ss -tulpen | grep ssh
```

shows me that endlessh it is set to port 2222.
Why is port 2222 being watched even though I have port 22 set in endlessh config?

And there is only a empty endlessh.service file in /etc/systemd/system/
Instead the non-empty endlessh.service file is in /lib/systemd/system/

Here /etc/systemd/system/endlessh.service I made these changes:

> If you want Endlessh to bind on ports < 1024
>
> 1. run:
>
> ```
> setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/endlessh
> ```
>
> 2. uncomment following line
>
> ```
> AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
> ```
>
> 3. comment following line
>
> ```
> #PrivateUsers=true
> ```

However this did not work:

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/endlessh
```

I get this:

> Failed to set capabilities on file `/usr/local/bin/endlessh' (No such file or directory)
> The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file

Edit: After

> systemctl daemon-reload

it monitors Port 22 now. Although this command still don't work:

> setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/endlessh

Why most Tutorials about Endlessh write to compile it from git instead to install it easily with apt install endlessh?

Answer (score 0):

The port 22 specification is read from the config file upon program startup. Once you've changed the config file, you must restart the program to get it to read the new, improved, config file.